# Home automation protocols to use for wifi

Tags: home-automation

I am trying to zero in on which home automation protocol to use for my embedded device. I have a wireless module which connects to a router. So the protocol has to operate over wifi. I know I will not be able to use Zigbee and Zwave since these dont operate over the 802.11 layer. I was wondering if there is any open source home automation protocol which is a standard and which has been implemented for wifi or is independent of the medium of transmission of messages ? Also I am targeting embedded systems so if there is a C library to use that someone knows about or a open source project written in C for home automation , please let me know.

Comment: Can you detail a little bit your idea/project ? Also can you give some info about your embedded device ? (type of microcontroller, external memory, etc.)

Comment: Note: the reason people use zigbee and zwave is that wifi power consumption is far too high for long-term battery-powered devices.

Answer (score 1):

Since IP is the protocol to rule them all ([What is the best wired protocol choice for home automation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/what-is-the-best-wired-protocol-choice-for-home-automation?rq=1)),

What about IP6LowPan? Might be a bit of an overkill though.